# WebSockets and text encoding

Tags: javascript, websocket

I read:

> The WebSocket API accepts a DOMString object, which is encoded as
>   UTF-8 on the wire, or one of ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, or Blob
>   objects for binary transfers.

A `DOMString` is a UTF-16 encoded string. So is it correct that UTF-8 encoding is used over the wire?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes, it is correct.

UTF-16 may or may not be used in memory, that is just an implementation detail of whatever framework you are using.  In the case of JavaScript, strings are UTF-16.

For WebSocket communications, UTF-8 must be used over the wire for textual data (most Internet protocols use UTF-8 nowadays).  That is dictated by the [WebSocket protocol specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455):

> After a successful handshake, clients and servers transfer data back and forth in conceptual units referred to in this specification as "messages".  On the wire, a message is composed of one or more frames.  The WebSocket message does not necessarily correspond to a particular network layer framing, as a fragmented message may be coalesced or split by an intermediary.
>
> A frame has an associated type.  Each frame belonging to the same message contains the same type of data.  Broadly speaking, **there are types for textual data (which is interpreted as UTF-8 [RFC3629] text)**, binary data (whose interpretation is left up to the application), and control frames (which are not intended to carry data for the application but instead for protocol-level signaling, such as to signal that the connection should be closed).  This version of the protocol defines six frame types and leaves ten reserved for future use.
>
> ...
>
> Data frames (e.g., non-control frames) are identified by opcodes where the most significant bit of the opcode is 0.  Currently defined opcodes for data frames include **0x1 (Text)**, 0x2 (Binary).  Opcodes 0x3-0x7 are reserved for further non-control frames yet to be defined.
>
> Data frames carry application-layer and/or extension-layer data.  The opcode determines the interpretation of the data:
>
> Text
>
> **The "Payload data" is text data encoded as UTF-8**.  Note that a particular text frame might include a partial UTF-8 sequence; however, **the whole message MUST contain valid UTF-8**.  Invalid UTF-8 in reassembled messages is handled as described in Section 8.1.
>
> Binary
>
> The "Payload data" is arbitrary binary data whose interpretation is solely up to the application layer.

You will incure a small amount of overhead converting from UTF-16 to UTF-8 to UTF-16, but the overhead is minimal on modern machines, and conversions between UTFs are lossless.